# How can I make an if and elif statement based on an outcome of random.choice and an input

Tags: python, string, if-statement, random

I am trying to create a game that asks you what a certain character does in a book and I am using random.choice and an if and elif statement to do that however when I type my input to answer the question the output is always wrong even though i answered the question wright.

I have tried to make the if statement:

```
if 'The main character' in card_list and choice == person1:
  print("correct")
```

for every statement however the results are always correct even if i type in the wrong answer.

```
import random

card1 = 'The main character'
card2 = 'He brings aleem on holiday'
card3 = 'Dies in the middle of the book'
card4 = "She takes care of aleem while aleem's dad is in Ethiopia"
card5 = 'He helps take care of aleem with Miss Fitzgerald'
card6 = "He is in charge of aleem's court case"

person1 = 'aleem'
person2 = "aleem's dad"
person3 = "aleem's mum"
person4 = 'Miss Fitzgerald'
person5 = 'Mr Fitzgerald'
person6 = 'Nicolas'

card_list = [card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6]

print(random.choice(card_list))

choice = input('Who is this? ')

if 'The main character' == random.choice and choice == person1:
  print("correct")
elif 'He brings aleem on holiday' == random.choice and choice == 
person2:
  print('correct')
elif 'Dies in the middle of the book' == random.choice and choice == 
person3:
  print('correct')
elif "She takes care of aleem while aleem's dad is in Ethiopia" == 
random.choice and choice == person4:
  print('correct')
elif 'He helps take care of aleem with Miss Fitzgerald' == 
random.choice and choice == person5:
  print('correct')
elif "He is in charge of aleem's court case" == random.choice and 
choice == person6:
  print('correct')
else:
  print('wrong')
```

This is what I have been using to create the game.

Comment: You are trying to compare a method (`random.choice()`) to  a string. Try storing the output of the method to a variable instead of printing it and compare that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not saving the random card in a variable so that you can tally it later,

```
if 'The main character' == random.choice and choice == person1:
```

random.choice returns method object which will never be same as string "The main character"

Fixed code:

```
import random

card1 = 'The main character'
card2 = 'He brings aleem on holiday'
card3 = 'Dies in the middle of the book'
card4 = "She takes care of aleem while aleem's dad is in Ethiopia"
card5 = 'He helps take care of aleem with Miss Fitzgerald'
card6 = "He is in charge of aleem's court case"

person1 = 'aleem'
person2 = "aleem's dad"
person3 = "aleem's mum"
person4 = 'Miss Fitzgerald'
person5 = 'Mr Fitzgerald'
person6 = 'Nicolas'

card_list = [card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6]

random_card = random.choice(card_list)
print(random_card)

choice = input('Who is this? ')

if 'The main character' == random_card and choice == person1:
  print("correct")
elif 'He brings aleem on holiday' == random_card and choice == person2:
  print('correct')
elif 'Dies in the middle of the book' == random_card and choice == person3:
  print('correct')
elif "She takes care of aleem while aleem's dad is in Ethiopia" == random_card and choice == person4:
  print('correct')
elif 'He helps take care of aleem with Miss Fitzgerald' == random_card and choice == person5:
  print('correct')
elif "He is in charge of aleem's court case" == random_card and choice == person6:
  print('correct')
else:
  print('wrong')
```

Answer (score 0):

try the switch case blog and rand integer range(0,6)

```
 import random

card1 = 'The main character'
card2 = 'He brings aleem on holiday'
card3 = 'Dies in the middle of the book'
card4 = "She takes care of aleem while aleem's dad is in Ethiopia"
card5 = 'He helps take care of aleem with Miss Fitzgerald'
card6 = "He is in charge of aleem's court case"

person1 = 'aleem'
person2 = "aleem's dad"
person3 = "aleem's mum"
person4 = 'Miss Fitzgerald'
person5 = 'Mr Fitzgerald'
person6 = 'Nicolas'

card_list = [card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6]

print(random.choice(card_list))

  def numbers_to_strings(argument): 
    switcher = { 
        0: "card1", 
        1: "card2", 
        2: "card3"...
    } 

    return switcher.get(argument, "nothing") 



choice = input('Who is this? ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative methods:

Using index of the list:

```
card_list = [card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6]
person_list= [person1, person2, person3, person4, person5, person6]
rand_choice=random.choice(card_list)
print(rand_choice)
choice = input('Who is this? ')

if choice in person_list and person_list.index(choice)==card_list.index(rand_choice):
    print('correct')
else:
    print('wrong')
```

Using dictionary:

```
card_list = [card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6]
person_list= [person1, person2, person3, person4, person5, person6]
d = {p:c for p,c in zip(person_list, card_list)}
rand_choice=random.choice(card_list)
print(rand_choice)
choice = input('Who is this? ')

if choice in d and rand_choice==d.get(choice):
    print('correct')
else:
    print('wrong')
```